# ASP.Net MVC Route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area called MyArea and it's registered like so:

```
context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea", new { controller = "MyAreaController", action = "Index" });

//Properties
context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea/properties", new { controller = "Property", action = "Index" });
context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea/properties/edit/{propertyId}", new { controller = "Property", action = "Property" });

//Units
context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea/properties/edit/{propertyId}/units/{unitId}", new { action = "Unit", propertyId = 1, unitId = 1 });
```

It should work that one property has many units, so I would like my url to look something like this:

http://localhost:50182/myarea/properties/edit/4/units/1

The code i use for the Html.ActionLink looks like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add new Unit", "Unit", "Unit", new { propertyId = 1, unitId = 1 })
```

I have an Unit controller with an action called Unit. Pleas help, what am i missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: the link goes to http://localhost:50182/myarea/properties/edit/4/units?controller=Property&Length=4 

rather than :

http://localhost:50182/myarea/properties/edit/4/units/1

and I get the following error messsage:

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: controllerName

Answer (score 1):

You say "I have an Unit controller with an action called Unit. Pleas help, what am i missing?"

and your route mapping is currently ...

```
 context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea/properties/edit/{propertyId}/units/{unitId}", new { action = "Unit", propertyId = 1, unitId = 1 });
```

How would you expect MVC to know what controller to use for that route?  You need to specify `controller = "Unit"`

**Update**

Switch the order of

```
   context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea/properties/edit/{propertyId}", new { controller = "Property", action = "Property" });

   //Units
   context.MapRoute(null, "MyArea/properties/edit/{propertyId}/units/{unitId}", new { action = "Unit", propertyId = 1, unitId = 1 });
```

in your route registration.  Otherwise, something that should map to the second route will be intercepted by the first.

Comment: I did try that but the the url then goes to:

http://localhost:50182/myarea/properties/edit/

Comment: Swopped it around, but the url this goes to localhost:50182/myarea/properties/edit

Comment: and, you set the controller = "Unit" ?  You must at least be getting a querystring...

Comment: yip it looks like this: context.MapRoute(null, "myarea/properties/edit/{propertyId}/units/{unitId}", new { controller="Unit", action = "Unit", propertyId = 1, unitId = 1 });

Comment: My Html.Actionlink looks like this: Is it correct? @Html.ActionLink("Add new Unit", "Unit", "Unit", new { propertyId = 1, unitId = 1 })

Comment: (1)  There are reasons you shouldn't give the propertyId and unitId default values, but that shouldn't be affecting this.  (2) What is the url that your action link maps to using this route?

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all.  Even if it were catching the route, it should have the additional parameters, `propertyId` and `unitId`,  as querystring parameters.  Maybe you need to rebuild the solution?  This is not the correct behavior.